# My swift app needs access to photo library. I've set access, but still get an error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've added in info.plist new row:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>user message</string>
```

But I still the error: "[ERROR] Could not create a bookmark: NSError: Cocoa 257 "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you [request authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_a_great_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app)?

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { status in
switch status {
case .notDetermined:
    // The user hasn't determined this app's access.
case .restricted:
    // The system restricted this app's access.
case .denied:
    // The user explicitly denied this app's access.
case .authorized:
    // The user authorized this app to access Photos data.
case .limited:
    // The user authorized this app for limited Photos access.
@unknown default:
    fatalError()
}
}
```